# How to start GnuPG SSH Agent for gvfs?

Tags: systemd, gnome3, gpg, gpg-agent, gvfs

I use Gnome 3.36.3 (Ubuntu 20.04.1) with GnuPG 2.2.19 as SSH agent.

I tell OpenSSH where to find the GnuPG SSH agent socket in my `~/.profile` file:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
```

This works fine in terminal windows. Whenever I connect to a remote SSH server, I get prompted for my PIN.

But when I try to connect to a remote SFTP server with Nautilus, I get errors, either an message like "not authorized!" or I am asked for username and password (which of course won't work as I use keys only).

As a manual workaround I found out, that after a `pkill gvfsd` and a complaining beep from Nautilus, SFTP connections will work as expected.

So apparently **gvfs** is not aware of my GnuPG SSH agent after login. but will be later, when killed and restarted.

What do I have to do, to make **gvfs** aware of my GnuPG SSH agent, wwithout killing manually first?

Comment: Debian (and probably Ubuntu) set SSH_AUTH_SOCK to the gpg-agent socket in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent`.  I wonder if gvfs is getting started earlier than this in session start up.  You should start by checking what `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set to in the gvfs process's environment.  Find its PID, and run `tr "\0" "\n" < /proc/<pid>/environ` to check.

Comment: Thanks @satwell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR:

`sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/90gpg-agent && reboot`

The Longread:

When opening remote locations with Nautilus, the gvfs-daemon takes care of
connecting to the remote system and mounting its file-system in the background.

gvfs is managed by systemd. And systemd seems to manage its own environment
independently of what you put in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Somehow later in the session, i.e. when a bash terminal window was opened, the
environment setup `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` might be available to
newly started processes, but not right from the beginning. I am not really sure
how this part works, but the resulting facts are easily observable:

If you look at the environment of the gvfs-daemon.service right after login you
see the following:

```
# Get the PID of the running gvfsd
$ FIXME=$(systemctl --user show --property="MainPID" gvfs-daemon.service | grep -o '[0-9]*')

# Show the environment of the running gvfsd
$ tr "\0" "\n" < "/proc/${FIXME}/environ"
```

You will see that the environment is a lot smaller compared to your bash
session with the `env` command: More importantly, there is no
SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable in the gvfsd process environment.

If you restart the the gvfs service now from your bash terminal and look at
the environment again:

```
$ systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon.service
$ FIXME=$(systemctl --user show --property="MainPID" gvfs-daemon.service | grep -o '[0-9]*')
$ tr "\0" "\n" < "/proc/${FIXME}/environ"
```

Now the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable is present, the SFTP client invoked by the
gvfs-daemon will use the gpg-agent-socket as SSH agent, and remote folders in
Nautilus will work as expected.

The Debian GnuPG package maintainers where [aware of this
problem](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=855868) and made a
systemd user environment generator script available at

`/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/90gpg-agent`.

However that script has its executable bit not set, and therefore is probably never
started.

After making it executable and rebooting the system, SFTP connections open as
expected right from the beginning.

```
$ sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/90gpg-agent
$ reboot
```

Note: While researching this I was mislead several times, because the
environment keeps changing while working on the system. To be sure, always do a
full system reboot. Just logging out and log back in of your Gnome session,
apparently doesn't reset everything to the same state as right after a system
start.

Comment: I don't think your `ExecStartPre` is actually doing anything useful.  The environment variables set there won't propagate into the `gvfsd` process.  But by starting `gvfsd` as a user systemd service, you *are* getting the variables set by `/usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/90gpg-agent`. Which includes `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.  I bet you could remove your `ExecStartPre` and it would work just as well.

Comment: You are right. That did somehow work yesterday after a simple logout/login. It did not work anymore this morning after a full reboot.

Comment: After @satwell told me about ```/usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/90gpg-agent``` I noticed, that that script has no execution permissions set. So I reversed all my previous changes and did a ```sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/90gpg-agent```
Now the environment is set correctly and Nautilus can do SFTP just fine.

Comment: As a one-shot temporary fix I do: 
`systemctl --user set-environment SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK; systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon.service`